# Rails Sidekiq Mailer Job Url Helpers issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

Using Rails 6 with Active Job (Sidekiq backend) whenever I try to send a mail (deliver_later) with a link_to I get the following error:

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in background at 2019-11-25 17:18=
:11 -0300 :

  Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set defaul=
t_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I'm searching for days and found diferent solutions here in SO, but most of then are outdated and don't work anymore for rails 5+ .  What I tried so far (in development.rb):

> ```
> > Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "https://myhost.com"
> > 
> > 
> > config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => https://"myhost.com" }
> >   
> > 
> > config.default_url_options = { :host => https://"myhost.com" }
> >
> ```

None of then seems to work. Is there any more aproches to this?

EDIT:

In my mailer/view I'm trying to use the link_to like this:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:25px;">Para redefinir tua senha, <%= link_to "CLIQUE AQUI", reset_password_registration_url(token: @token) %></p>
```

Comment: Did you try to set it with port number? Like so:  `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost", port: 3000 }` . No need for `https` or `https`

Comment: AFAIK this configuration didn't change in Rails 6. Did you restart the server after editing `development.rb`?

Comment: @nuaky Yes. I tried setting a port on the hash. Http/https will matter for me once in production, wouldn't?

Comment: @Toribio Yes, I restart the local (puma) server in each attempt